# Apphost executable failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am a dot net developer, i just updated my Vscode to the latest version and somewhat I am having issues building my web api project, Anytime I want to build any web api project it always pops an error

> NETSDK1029; unable to use C:\Users\…….nuget
> \packages\Microsoft.netcore.app.host.win-x64\6.0.13\runtimes\win-x64\native\apphost.exe
> as application host executable as it does not contain the expected
> placeholder byte sequence

I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it, I also downloaded latest  SDK version all effort prove abortive

Comment: Did you try clearing the nuget cache, or even deleting the contents of that folder and doing a restore?

Comment: Yes, I just did that now and it worked..Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. I just added the comment as an answer, so if you accept that, it would help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, the first thing to do is clear the Nuget package cache. The easiest way to do that is to delete the contents of the `C:\Users\…….nuget \packages` folder, either the whole thing (safest) or just the subfolder for the offending package.

Then do a package restore from VS and see if it helps.